# Can $S_R(A)$ always be embedded into $S_R(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, computability

Suppose $A$ is a recursively enumerable subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Let’s call a $\mu$-recursive function $f$ a *recursive permutation* of $A$, if it is undefined on $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ and $f|_A$ is a bijection of $A$ onto itself. Let’s denote the set of all recursive permutations of $A$ as $S_R(A)$. It is not hard to see, that $S_R(A)$ forms a group under composition.

Can $S_R(A)$ always be recursively embedded in $S_R(\mathbb{N})$?

If $A$ were decidable, then the question would have been easy: in that case we would have always been able to define the embedding as $f \mapsto g$, where

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}  f(x) & \quad x \in A \\ x & \quad x \notin A \end{cases}$$

However, this construction is not possible if $A$ is recursively enumerable, but not decidable. But maybe there is some other way to recursively embed $S_R(A)$ into $S_R(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: If you want each $f\in S_R(A)$ to be mapped to a recursive extension of $f$ then the answer is no. I guess you want the embedding to be somewhat simple (computable?), otherwise you can biject $A$ to a computable subset $B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ and use the embedding $S_R(B)\to S_R(\mathbb{N})$ to induce and embedding $S_R(A)\to S_R(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: @Manlio, yes, I wanted the embedding $S_R(A) \to S_R(\mathbb{N})$ to be computable (but, unfortunately, forgot to clarify this)

Comment: Just to be sure of the definition of $S_R(A)$: does this mean the set of recursively enumerable subsets of $\mathbf{N}^2$ which are graph of permutations of $A$ (i.e., both of whose projections are injective of image $A$)?

Comment: @YCor, yes. That is the most natural way to define it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm not sure I know what is a computable map between these groups (since $S_R(\mathbf{N})$ is not computable, and probably $S_R(A)$ is also not computable).